# How do I get a row based on its ROWID?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a data table written in an SQLite Database and I want to retrieve it based on the ROWID, for example row 3? I tried `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWID=3;` but that didn't work.

EDIT: What I am hoping to achieve is retrieve just the 3rd row without using the `LIMIT` function. I thought I could achieve this using the ROWID, but I see I can't do that.

Comment: "that didn't work" -- what does this mean? Did you get some sort of SQL error? Did you get an empty result set? Something else?

Comment: post your code for query

Comment: @CommonsWare, it returned an empty result set

Comment: Possibly, no one of your rows has a rowid of 3. Even if there are 3 or more rows.

Comment: Is it possible to get the database to output just the 3rd row?

Comment: No, because there is no concept of "the 3rd row". Do not think of a database table as being a `List`. Think of it as being a `Set`. The results of a query with an `ORDER BY` clause gives you a `List`, and `OFFSET`/`LIMIT` is the only way I know of to give you a subset of that list based on an index into the raw query results.

Comment: select * from table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2 . would this solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

`LIMIT`
It specifies a limited number of rows in the result set to be returned based on number_rows.

`OFFSET`
Optional. The first row returned by LIMIT will be determined by offset_value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a cursor for this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + YOUR_TABLE + " where ROWID = 3", null)

String info = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME));
//repeat this for all your different columns (different strings or just append to info depending on what you want achieve

cursor.close() //remember to close the cursor
```